How to manage create tags in GCP Data Catalog on row level
I want to create Data Catalog tags for specific row which I process in Data Fusion - e.g. Warning tag to underline that specific row not completely passed all validations of pipeline, but it's said that Data Catalog is not supporting row level tags - I can't understand this as I think mostly row level tags happing in my use cases
Please help how to workaround this (solution with custom columns for tag as obvious)

Hi ,  creating  Data Catalog tags for a specific row is not supported by GCP , you can use row lavel tagging with Bigquey . Check this document bigquery row level limitations

HI, If you found that information helpful please do upvote or accept as per Stack Overflow guidelines , helping more Stack contributors with their research .

Currently creating Data Catalog tags for a specific row is not supported by GCP , you can use row lavel tagging with Bigquey . Check this document bigquery row level limitations   .
If you want that feature you can open a new Feature request as per your requirements on the public issue tracker  describing your issue and vote [+1]  and Eng team will look on the feature for future implementation .
